# signed-by in mail header is not added as I have installed and configured my domain

Tags: email, postfix, spam

I have checked in http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck that my site has a valid TXT record for `DKIM`. My domain is `myDomain.com` and my selector is `mail`.

[image]

I used `-t` and says to servers to ignore errors and don't drop it in header. (If I'm wrong in any way please tell)

`TXT` record is also added and working. (The record has been for in `dkimcore` website).

Now when my domain send an email there is no signed-by in mail header.

The command I used to generate `mail.txt` is as below:

```
opendkim-genkey -t -s mail -d myDomain.com
```

`opendkim.conf` file has this line and `dkim.key` exists:

```
KeyFile                 /etc/mail/dkim.key
```

Where should I put `mail.private` which is generated by the command I explained above?

I removed `-t` in generation and now email is not sent at all. Error log says:

```
dkim_eom(): resource unavailable: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed
```

**EDIT:**

`d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed` is resolved. When key is generated its permissions was as below:

```
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  312 Feb  6 12:43 dkim.key
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  887 Feb  6 12:43 mail.private
```

I've added both keys to `opendkim` group as its service is running by that user. It is bizarre that when you generate a key by `opendkim-genkey` the permissions are not handled correctly. Anyway I am on the previous error again. I receive the error:

```
connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused
```

Is this a permission issue of folders like postfix and openDKIM?

When I change permission I cannot restart `opendkim` service and it fails, so I changed permissions to its first state. Now I receive the first error.

**EDIT 2:**

`Postfix` configuration:

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

`openDKIM` configuration in `/etc/default/opendkim`:

```
SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost" # listen on loopback on port 8891
```

`/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
Domain                  Mydomain.com
KeyFile                 /etc/mail/dkim.key
Selector                mail
```

This is the error I currently receive:

```
SSL error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag; error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error; error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag; error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error; error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib; error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag; error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
dkim_eom(): resource unavailable: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed
```

Reverse DNS of domain says:

```
4 hours PTR *-*-*-*.nrp.co
Authoritative Nameservers
ns1.nrp.co
ns2.nrp.co
ns3.nrp.co

ServFail Response: ns2.nrp.co  
Authoritative Nameservers
ns1.nrp.co
ns3.nrp.co
ns2.nrp.co
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I used public key in `KeyFile` instead of `PrivateKey`:

```
KeyFile                 /etc/mail/dkim.key
```

Changed to:

```
KeyFile                 /etc/mail/dkim.private
```

The problem is gone but `DKIM` signature is not shown on google side. There is not error log in `mail.err` every thing seems working on this side.

I even digged `TXT` to see if `DKIM` is present:

```
dig mail._domainkey.myDomain.com TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mail._domainkey.myDomain.com TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5849
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 6

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail._domainkey.myDomain.com.  IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail._domainkey.myDomain.com. 28800 IN  TXT "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; t=y\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHZPuhZKOmy4c9pA7jhYHOLIV4a0RNcBbX7NYJ04hVAj1Dm241YL9+cmhSeggt8OaJVuJKlmmFYUiCuj9UUAc7dgiqBsy+2Tvct+/FFrEhlL8lP9AtISCKkKmBTDBQ/2A6flSokQGr6CwGdLnjQXjp9JepxFjmu+J834RYCnIM1wIDAQAB
```

Comment: what size key? google treats keys under 1024 as unsigned.

Comment: @JacobEvans, DKIM signature is shown now. Problem is that my email is in `spam` folder`. At first emails were inside of inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the reverse dns of you domain? And are you sending the `sender` header in you email? As per me these two are required.

Comment: I use third party for DNS, how to check if it exists? how to send `sender` header in mail? Do you mean `from`

Comment: Sender is not from. It is different mail header. And for reverse dns you need to check the PTR record is set or not.

Comment: See the last response for reverse DNS please. I don't set `sender` anywhere how to set that? For reverse DNS they are not my NSes! what are those?

Comment: they are the NSes of you hosting provided. Please get them corrected from the guise where you got the server. Sender is set in the body of you mail. Which client you are using to send the mail?

Comment: With the last error I've shown I cannot send emails at all! How to solve that problem?

Comment: while starting opendkim service what error you are getting?